# What is the easiest way to update a textView from a service?

Tags: java, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

I am making an app which consists of an activity and a service. By pressing a button the service is started, it collects data in the background from a sensor and classifies it and outputs a string. I want to display the string in a textView. Right now I can see in the log that the variable is updated 2 times every second, but when I try and update the textView from the service class nothing is happening unless I press the button, whenever I press the button, the string is displayed in the textView.

What is the easiest solution here? I tried to make the textView static and it still can't update it. Can you make it so that the view is updated automatically every second? Can I add a listener somehow? Since I am not very experienced I would like an easy solution that does not have to be a "good" one.

Here is my code

Activity:

```
public class CollectorActivity extends Activity {

private enum State {
    IDLE, COLLECTING, TRAINING, CLASSIFYING
};

private final String[] mLabels = { Globals.CLASS_LABEL_STANDING,
        Globals.CLASS_LABEL_WALKING, Globals.CLASS_LABEL_RUNNING,
        Globals.CLASS_LABEL_OTHER };

private RadioGroup radioGroup;
private final RadioButton[] radioBtns = new RadioButton[4];
private Intent mServiceIntent;
private File mFeatureFile;
public static TextView mCurrentLabel;

private State mState;
private Button btnDelete;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupLabels);
    radioBtns[0] = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioStanding);
    radioBtns[1] = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioWalking);
    radioBtns[2] = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioRunning);
    radioBtns[3] = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioOther);

    btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteData);
    mCurrentLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mState = State.IDLE;
    mFeatureFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
            Globals.FEATURE_FILE_NAME);
    mServiceIntent = new Intent(this, SensorsService.class);


}



public void onCollectClicked(View view) {

    if (mState == State.IDLE) {
        mState = State.COLLECTING;
        ((Button) view).setText(R.string.ui_collector_button_stop_title);
        btnDelete.setEnabled(false);
        radioBtns[0].setEnabled(false);
        radioBtns[1].setEnabled(false);
        radioBtns[2].setEnabled(false);
        radioBtns[3].setEnabled(false);

        int acvitivtyId = radioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(radioGroup
                .getCheckedRadioButtonId()));
        String label = mLabels[acvitivtyId];

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(Globals.CLASS_LABEL_KEY, label);
        mServiceIntent.putExtras(extras);

        startService(mServiceIntent);

    } else if (mState == State.COLLECTING) {
        mState = State.IDLE;
        ((Button) view).setText(R.string.ui_collector_button_start_title);
        btnDelete.setEnabled(true);
        radioBtns[0].setEnabled(true);
        radioBtns[1].setEnabled(true);
        radioBtns[2].setEnabled(true);
        radioBtns[3].setEnabled(true);

        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).cancelAll();
    }
}

public void onDeleteDataClicked(View view) {

    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment
            .getExternalStorageState())) {
        if (mFeatureFile.exists()) {
            mFeatureFile.delete();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.ui_collector_toast_file_deleted,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (mState == State.TRAINING) {
        return;
    } else if (mState == State.COLLECTING || mState == State.CLASSIFYING) {
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .cancel(Globals.NOTIFICATION_ID);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Stop the service and the notification.
    // Need to check whether the mSensorService is null or not.
    if (mState == State.TRAINING) {
        return;
    } else if (mState == State.COLLECTING || mState == State.CLASSIFYING) {
        stopService(mServiceIntent);
        ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                .cancelAll();
    }
    finish();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

And this is the "doInBackground" method in my service class. The line "CollectorActivity.mCurrentLabel.setText(classification);" is the problem. I want this to update the textView continously.

```
 public class OnSensorChangedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



        Instance inst = new DenseInstance(mFeatLen);
        inst.setDataset(mDataset);
        Instance inst2 = new DenseInstance(65);
        int blockSize = 0;
        FFT fft = new FFT(Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY);
        double[] accBlock = new double[Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY];
        double[] re = accBlock;
        double[] im = new double[Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY];

        double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;

        while (true) {
            try {
                // need to check if the AsyncTask is cancelled or not in the while loop
                if (isCancelled () == true)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // Dumping buffer
                accBlock[blockSize++] = mAccBuffer.take().doubleValue();


                if (blockSize == Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY) {
                    blockSize = 0;
                    testList = new ArrayList<Double>();

                    // time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    max = .0;
                    for (double val : accBlock) {
                        if (max < val) {
                            max = val;
                        }
                    }

                    fft.fft(re, im);

                    for (int i = 0; i < re.length; i++) {
                        double mag = Math.sqrt(re[i] * re[i] + im[i]
                                * im[i]);
                        inst.setValue(i, mag);
                        testList.add(i,mag);
                        im[i] = .0; // Clear the field
                    }

                    // Append max after frequency component
                    inst.setValue(Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY, max);
                    inst2.setValue(Globals.ACCELEROMETER_BLOCK_CAPACITY, max);
                    testList.add(max);


                     classificationIndex = WekaClassifier.classify(testList.toArray());
                     classification = testLabel.get((int) classificationIndex);
                     CollectorActivity.mCurrentLabel.setText(classification);

                    inst.setValue(mClassAttribute, mLabel);
                    mDataset.add(inst);
                    Log.i("new instance", mDataset.size() + "");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In `doInBackground(Void... arg0)` change  `CollectorActivity.mCurrentLabel.setText(classification);` to `publishProgress(classification);` then change second argument from `Void` to `String`:     `public class OnSensorChangedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Srting, Void>` and add `onProgressUpdate()`.

Finally your code should looks like:

```
public class OnSensorChangedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Srting, Void> {

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    //...
    publishProgress(classification);
    //...
}

@Override
protected Void onProgressUpdate(String... classification) {
     CollectorActivity.mCurrentLabel.setText(classification[0]);
}
```